# 10.14: Only display full path in a Finder window's title bar and not in its tabs?

Tags: finder, mojave

I just finally updated to Mojave, and there's a new behavior in the Finder for those of us that set the hidden preference `_FXShowPosixPathInTitle` to true.

Previously when using that setting in 10.13, tabs in Finder windows would only display the name of their folder. Now they display the full path of their folder, just like the title bar.

I have a Finder window with eight tabs in it that I use as part of my daily workflow. Sufficed to say it's now impossible to tell which tab is for which folder because I can only see the first twelve characters of the path. (i.e. /Users/myusername/ -- not very helpful!)

Is there any way of getting the old behavior back? Or perhaps some other solution to this problem?

Comment: I'm able to see the full path on the tab not just the first 12 characters in 10.14.2.

Comment: @MarcelWilson I can too so long as I only have a few tabs open and the path to their folder isn't too long. The issue is when the path is so long that it can't fit in the tabs' width.

Comment: ahh.. I see your point.  Open enough longer locations and it starts truncating.